# I have 'use-strict' mode in JS enabled implicitly

Tags: javascript, use-strict

It turns out that I have 'use-strict' enabled and I don't know why...

```
const isStrict = () => !this
console.log( isStrict() );
```

This code returns me `true` and I'm testing it in a plain `.js` file, without dependencies or anything. Maybe an extension could be interfering?

**Edit:**
Okay, I realized that It's running in strict-mode because I was using ES6 Modules

`<script type="module" src="main.js" defer ></script>`

Didn't know that every ES6 module runs in strict-mode

Should I answer my own question or editing it like this is fine? Sorry, I'm new asking questions here

Comment: Please show us how you call this function and how/where you include/execute that "plain `.js` file".

Answer (score 0):

Strict mode is enabled by default when using ES6 Modules. See [Strict mode on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#strict_mode_for_modules).

As far as I am aware, there is no way to disable this feature.